# Anisotropic form over a field implies anisotropic over K(X)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm a bit confusse and i dont know how to solve this problem.

Let S be an anisotropic system of forms (non constant homogeneous polynomials) over K. Show that S is anisotropic over the rational function field K(X).

Comment: What do you mean by an "anisotropic system of forms"? What kind of forms are you talking about here?

Comment: non constant homogeneus polynomials

Comment: What does anisotropic mean?

Comment: f $\in$ K[X] is anisotropic if f(x) = 0 iff x=0

Answer (score 1):

We will assume that the field $K$ is infinite and do this for just one such form.

Let $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ be such a form. If $f$ is isotropic over $K(t)$, we have a non-zero vector $(g_1(t),\ldots, g_n(t))$ with $g_i(t)\in K(t)$ such that $f(g_1,\ldots, g_n)=0$. Write $g_i(t)=P_i(t)/F(t)$ for polynomials $P_i,F\in K[t]$. Then, by homogeneity, it is clear that $f(P_1,\ldots, P_n)=0$. Since at least one of the $P_i\neq 0$ and the field is infinite, we can find $a\in K$ such that at least one of $P_i(a)\neq 0$. Then, it is clear that $f(P_1(a),\ldots, P_n(a))=0$, contradicting the assumption.